# Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am trying to create a database for my rails 5.0.0.1 application with `rails db:create` but I receive the following error:

```
Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
```

The point is that there is a `gem 'pg'` in my Gemfile, which was updated to version 1.0.0 by `bundle update`, launched after `bundle install`:

```
$ gem list
...
pg (1.0.0, 0.20.0)
```

I have no idea why rails cannot recognize the installed pg gem and fails to create a database for my application.

Answer (score 0):

pg version 1.0.0 work fine with rails 5.1.5 and newer.
See this github [post](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31673)